# HTML page doesn't goes up along with input field

Tags: javascript, html, css, ejs

How to implement,when a user click input field then whole html page goes up along
with input field.
[This is the output i got.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWb1S.png)    [This is the expected output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIDTp.png) [This is html code and](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okDMe.png)[This is css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KRLk.png)
How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use fixed values for height like % and vh 
Give height of 100vh or 100% to the parent element

```
height:100vh;
```

or

```
height:100%;
```

Comment: Welcome! Glad to hear that